# Plugin not firing when using "Manage Members" on a marketing list in CRM 2013

Tags: plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Good afternoon. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this. Inside of a Dynamics CRM 2013 environment, I have a custom entity which holds 3 data grids. Whenever a record (of contact, account or lead) is added to its respective datagrid, it adds the record to a static marketing list via a custom plugin I wrote. The trouble I'm having is that when I use the "Manage Members" (to add/remove records using the advanced find feature) it's not firing at all. The plugin IS firing correctly when I add/remove items from the custom entity using the "+" and "trash can" buttons. The RemoveMember portion is firing when I use "Remove from Marketing List" button list as well, just not from "Manage Members". I have three steps registered on this plugin, associate on post-op/sync, disassociate on pre-op/sync, and removemember on post-op/sync. The idea is to be able to add or remove records from my custom entity OR the marketing list, and it auto-updates the other.

Does anybody have any suggestions or advice on how to fire a plugin when using the "Manage Members" portion of marketing lists? I've tried all valid combinations of messages and steps that I could think of, and I've written and re-written the code a few times to try to get it to work. Below is a pastebin with my code.

http://pastebin.com/X1n017Nr

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a second plugin and moved the logic for AddMember into it. I have no idea why, but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, hope this can help you:

Register the plug-in on the 'Update' Message.

Ask for the parentContext.Message AddMember, RemoveMember y AddMembersByFetchXml, the last one maybe is the message you can't find.

Do the logic you need with de message.

This worked for CRM2011.